# Read only specific column in delimited file using batch script

Tags: batch-file, csv

I am trying to read a csv file with different file structure every time. I want to create a batch script to fetch only specific columns based on column name (not column position as it changes every time) and create a new delimited file only with those specific columns.  For example we have below csv file data:

```
Subject,ID,Error

S1,a_11,error1

S2,b_11,error2
```

ID column can come anywhere in the file but Error would always be the last column.
Any suggestions are welcome. Also I have very little knowledge about batch scripting. Would really appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty incomplete. There are several details that are missing, so I have to guess them in order to write a working Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%~1" equ "" echo Usage: %0 column names ... & goto :EOF

rem Read the header and extract column names
set /P "header=" < test.csv
set "n=0"
for %%a in (%header%) do (
   set /A "n+=1, column[%%~a]=n"
)

rem Assemble output line from column names given in parameters
set "output="
:nextCol
   if not defined column[%~1] echo Not such column: "%~1" & goto :EOF
   set "output=!output!,%%!column[%~1]!"
   shift
if "%~1" neq "" goto nextCol

rem Generate output
for /F "tokens=1-%n% delims=," %%1 in (test.csv) do echo %output:~1%
```

These are the missing details:

- The "specific columns" in output file are given in the Batch file parameters.
- How many columns may have the input file? More than 9? More than 26? Current code can only output up to the 9th column in input file.
- May the data have columns that include a comma enclosed in quotes (like "Bill,Smith","ID32","Error1") or empty columns (like S1,,error1)? Current code can not process these cases.

These points can be changed in a posterior version...

Output example (assuming that the Batch file is called ExtractColumns.bat):

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Tests> ExtractColumns.bat Id,Subject
ID,Subject
a_11,S1
b_11,S2
```

Anyway, your "question" is just a code request, so if you want to receive further support you should show some effort from your part and post questions about specific doubts on the posted code...

Comment: the code worked. Thanks a lot. Also there can be any number of columns and the specific column could come at any position, so can u let me know how to handle that? Also if data comes enclosed in double quotes with comma, then how can I handle that as well? Thanks again. And yes, specific columns would be passed as parameters only to the batch script.

Comment: one more thing, If any column is blank which has been passed as parameter, then the code is skipping that column and picking column next to it with values. so how to fix that??

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use Windows NT command interpreter (cmd.exe), because it's impossible to do it in DOS/Win9x shell.

Here is a basic code that you can start paring a CSV within cmd.exe:

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A IN (yourfile.csv) DO (
    ECHO Subject: %%A
    ECHO ID: %%B
    ECHO Error: %%C
)
```

You should try `FOR /?` command and read its help. It would tell you how to use the `FOR /F` command to parse the file.

Comment: ok, now test the batch on this. `"Subject","ID","Error"
"S1,S2","a_11","error1" "S2,S3","b_11","error2"` :)

Comment: This method does not allow _"to read a csv file with different file structure every time"_ (as the OP specifically said in the question)...

Comment: @Aacini Sorry, but the "different file structure" is not clearly defined by OP. I don't know what to do.

The batch script is capable of handling _basic_ CSVs, so, as long as you don't have commas from within fields, it's OK to parse.
Otherwise, go find another tool or blame someone who handed in the peculiar CSV files to you.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Another caveat with `FOR /F` is that consecutive commas will collapse to one, i.e. empty fields will be parsed incorrectly. Windows batch will see `foo,,bar,,baz` as three fields in `FOR /F` instead of five.

Comment: IMHO OP's description is clear enough: _"I want to create a batch script to fetch only specific columns based on **column name** (not column position as it changes every time)... For example we have below csv file data: Subject,ID,Error... ID column can come anywhere in the file"_, that is, ID column not always comes in _second position_...

Answer (score 0):

Using `batchfile` is not really the best option for csv files. Though it can work, certain things like using `delims=,` will become problematic if you have a csv string like:

```
"Name,Surname","ID","Error" 
"Bill,Smith","ID32","Error1"
```

So above being 3 variables only, but contains additional commas.

instead use `Powershell`

```
$csvFilename = "D:\SomeFile.csv" 
$csv = Import-Csv $csvFilename -Header @("Subject","ID","Error")

foreach ($line in $csv) {
Write-Host "Subject=$($line.Subject)  ID=$($line.ID) Error=$($line.Error)"
    }
```

You can just save it as a `.ps1` file and run it in powershell, or calling powershell from command line.

Answer (score -2):

Windows batch scripting is not at all suited for this task.
While splitting a row on comma is quite simple, handling quotes and commas inside fields only with what cmd offers is infeasible.

Consider using scripting languages like Perl or Python for this.
For example, python has [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2) package, which has a convenient `csvcut` doing exactly what you want:

```
csvcut -c column_a,column_c data.csv > new.csv
```

Comment: Why downvotes? Is mentioning Perl or Python a taboo here?